# Gaussian curvature of ruled surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

> Let $c: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular curve, $V: I \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ a vector field and $a < b$. Then we call
>   $$
> f: (a,b)\times I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, \quad f(s,t):= c(t) +sV(t)
> $$
>   a *ruled surface*.
>
> Show that $f$ has gaussian curvature $K(s, t) \leq 0$.

For the first fundamental form, I obtained
$$
G = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \langle V, c'\rangle \\
\langle V, c'\rangle & \lvert c' + sV' \rvert^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and for the second fundamental form
$$
B = \frac{1}{\lvert V \times ( c' + sV') \rvert} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \langle V', V \times (c' + sV') \rangle \\
\langle V', V \times (c'+sV') \rangle & *
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and thus (with $V \perp V'$) that
$$
K = \frac{\det B}{\det G} = \frac{-2 \langle V', V\times c' \rangle}{\lvert c' + sV' \rvert^2 -2\langle V, c' \rangle} \cdot \frac{1}{\lvert V \times (c' + sV') \rvert}.
$$

I know that this question was already answered here: [Gaussian and Mean Curvatures for a Ruled Surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507529/gaussian-and-mean-curvatures-for-a-ruled-surface).

However, there are additional assumptions made such as $c' \perp V'$ and $\lvert V' \rvert = 1$. I don't know how to apply that as my case is a bit more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments:

First, you can see on geometric grounds that any ruled surface has $K\le 0$, as the rulings are asymptotic curves, and one cannot have asymptotic curves when $K>0$.

Second, you know that $\det G>0$ (always) and it's clear (from the $0$ in the $11$-entry) that $\det B\le 0$. So $\det B/\det G \le 0$.