# Surfaces generated by unit T,N,B

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

Are surfaces swept out by the normal, binormal and tangent of a regular curve on smooth continuous $\mathbb R^2 $ surfaces have zero Gauss curvature?

Is there a relationship for their surface parametrization in terms of geodesic curvature, geodesic torsion or other scalar properties of the curve?

Thanks for pointing to any literature sources on the subject.

Comment: If you're talking about a single regular curve, then T, N, B each sweep out another curve on $S^2$, no? If you're talking about all nice curves on a given surface, then I don't think T sweeps out a surface...

Comment: For example, if we take the normal $N$, do you consider all the line generated by $N$, and this for all $N$, therefore generating a **ruled** surface ? In this case, there are formulas for the different curvatures of a ruled surface. See for example : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2507529

Comment: Could you answer me about the fact that you consider a ruled surface or not ?

Comment: @runway44 For a circular helix we have *tangential developables* swept out by T, but what are surfaces developed by N,B in the moving triad?