# Ruled surface of constant Gauss Curvature modification

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

When polar coordinate $\theta $ equals "co-latitude" $\gamma, $ the ruled surface generated  has a constant negative Gauss curvature $ K=-\frac{1}{a^2}$ but only at the cuspidal edge $r=a.$ Only a half is shown for image clarity.

The parametrization is
$$ (x,y,z)=( r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, (a-r) \cot \theta ) $$

Is it possible to relate $\theta, \gamma $ so that $K$ is constant negative everywhere?

As this may not be possible, is there a curved generator connecting z-axis points to any other circle  points in order to get the same result?

EDIT 1:

In a particular case (conic/hypo pseudosphere) K=-1 can be obtained using curved asymptotes on a surface of revolution connecting points on $r=a$ to a point on z-axis.

Can all such paths.. whether ruled or not ruled, whether on a surface of revolution or not, be found by a defining ode?

Thanks so much for all suggestions!

[image]

Comment: By the formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507529/gaussian-and-mean-curvatures-for-a-ruled-surface), a ruled surface in Euclidean three-space cannot have constant negative Gaussian curvature. (In the notation of the linked question, for which $K = -\lambda^2/(\lambda^2+v^2)$, the function $\lambda$ depends only on $u$, while the denominator depends on $v$.)

Comment: In a particular case  (conic/hypo pseudosphere) K=-1 can be obtained using curved asymptotes on a surface of revolution connecting points on $r=a$ to a point on z-axis. Can all such paths in general be found?

Comment: For a surface or rotation or for a surface with helicoidal symmetry, yes (though mostly not explicitly, only as solutions of a differential equation). But if it matters, none of these are ruled.

Comment: Thanks again. Edited.. to find a variety of possible parameterizations / types of surface types .

Comment: I should be careful: By a _surface of rotation_ I mean specifically the surface swept by revolving a curve (not necessarily planar) about some axis; by a surface with _helicoidal symmetry_ I mean a surface swept by revolving a curve at constant angular speed about an axis while simultaneously translating along that axis. On closer reading, that may not be what you're asking. In the diagram it looks as if one end of the curve is rotating in a plane while the other is translating along an axis...?

Comment: In case it's of interest, a former student Xinyi Wang and I looked at isometric immersions of "Clairaut metrics," those of the form $E(u)\,du^2+G(u)\,dv^2$, obtaining a PDE for the second fundamental form, and in some cases solving analytically. (This may overlap with the question here, but if I understand, neither this question nor the results of our paper encompasses the other.)

Comment: Quite interesting, thanks.  Shall get back after collecting my thoughts. The sketch I made is from a described  problem from last pages of *Elementary treatise on Coordinate geom of 3d* , RJTBell, McMillan,London, Prob 99,Misc. examples, pp xliii.